# MySQL PHP group results by date and echo them

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

My MySQL Table

```
id, message, date
```

date is a timestamp

I would like it to be echoed in PHP like this:

```
Tuesday 20th August 2013 
- message 3
- message 2

Monday 19th August 2013 
- message 1
```

I have no idea how I would group the results and echo them for each day

Comment: `GROUP BY` + `ORDER BY` at SQL level + *loop* at PHP level?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Query

```
select group_concat(message), date from table group by date order by date
```

Now in code you get equal number of rows as dates and for each date messages as comma separate strings for example (date will be in timestamp - you can format that in code or mysql query)

20th Aug 2013 | message 3,message 1

19th August 2013 | message 2,message 4

Loop through each record and print date and then split the messages with , (comma) and print

Answer (score 0):

### SQL Query

SELECT id,message FROM messages ORDER BY date DESC

### PHP side

You have write a loop to print messages and write condition to "date" should not repeat again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,message FROM messages ORDER BY date DESC");
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $date = date("F j,Y",strtotime($row['date']));
    if(array_key_exists($date,$data)){
        $data[$date][] = array(
            'id'      => $row['id'],
            'message' => $row['message'],
        );
    }else{
        array_push($data,$data[$date]);
        $data[$date][] = array(
            'id'      => $row['id'],
            'message' => $row['message'],
        );
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
?>
```